# Nexus 6 got soaked in sea water. felt it overheat

Tags: motorola

i guess the power was on when it got dunked in sea water. Saw a blinking red light by the top speaker. Had it opened after maybe 36 hours. Some corrosion was already present. Can i stil save it? Will be willing to try anything. Just had it for 3 months. TIA for any helpful comments.

Already tried rinsing it in tap water and dried in rice before it was opened. should I try this process again now that its opened? its been 8 days already since it was submerged.